# Does WinPE have a default Administrator password?

Tags: windows, password, login, windows-pe

If so, what is it? And if it does not, how can I set it when configuring my WIM?

Comment: Quick answer is no, unless you connect from within an existing OS. Are you using boot.wim to boot into PE?

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I'm using boot.wim. Is there any file (like winpesh.ini) that I could change and add the admin password there?

Comment: Why do you need to set the PE admin password.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to set up OpenSSH (the version released by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/latest)) in WinPE. So far it runs and I can attempt a connection from another machine but it asks me for the password, and won't let me pass in a blank one. So that's why I'm interested in setting up the admin password on WinPE.

Answer (score 2):

Try below command on WinPE console which will activate the administrator user with password mentioned.

```
net user administrator admin123\ACTIVE:YES
```

Comment: However I think this is temporary, only during that session

Comment: Confirmed this works, thanks very much!!! Huge shout-out to colleague that pointed me to this thread. Using WinXPE WinBuilder and source WinPE from Windows 10 Bus. Ed. v2004 (Nov 2020) ISO, I had to disable the firewall and set user password: ```
net user Administrator myPassword /ACTIVE:yes
wpeutil.exe DisableFirewall
``` ... and that's all there was to it.